# Extracting specific corner of a rectangular polygon based on the cardinal direction

Tags: qgis, xy, direction

I have a dataset of rectangular polygons that have an arbitrary cardinal direction attribute (N, E, S, or W) assigned during digitization. The polygons aren't necessarily exactly rectangular.

I want to be able to find the X Y coordinate of the lower right-hand corner of the polygon from the perspective as if the cardinal direction was the 'top'.

The red points in the image below show what I'm looking for

[image]

I am using QGIS.

Comment: In your figure, the two rectangles on the left are off-axis and the direction arrows you have drawn are aligned with the rectangles, not the cardinal directions they are labeled with. Is that intentional? You suggest there is a possible problem with polygons angled 45°. Why? You say the assigned cardinal direction is in the data, so there is no ambiguity in knowing what direction to use. Finally, you say the polygons might no be exactly rectangular. Will they still have 4 vertices, or could they have more? Can they be arbitrary quadrilaterals, or are they pretty much rectangles to the eye?

Comment: The cardinal directions are arbitrarily assigned during digitization as N, E, S, or W. The rectangles appear rectangular to the eye, but may not be exactly right angles. They will not always have 4 vertices

Comment: Are the vertices digitized in the same order, and always four? Can you share your data?

Comment: Should it be a vertex or a point on the bound?